# Why does wordpress page change when I'm logged in?

Tags: wordpress

So something strange is going on and I was wondering if anyone could explain why, when i browse to my site not logged in as administrator the fonts and formatting are different from when i go to it normally. The site is updated so not sure where i should be looking so any advice would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes sure,
First you can check that your WordPress site having any cache plugin ?
if yes then deactivate that plugin and check your issue, after deactivate cache plugin your issue become solved than you can delete your site cache and after that activate cache plugin and check your site.

Comment: It fixed some thing but google fonts does not seem to load when not logged in.

Comment: I'm not sure but when i look in sources i can see when logged in fonts.gstatic.com is loaded but when logged out it is not, would this be a caching issue

Comment: Welcome @Uskompuf                                                                                                 if your problem has been solved, please don't forget to tick my answer as correct answer.

Comment: @Kabir  if your work done by my answer than please don't forget to tick my answer as correct answer.